# Converting CryptoJS encode to PHP

Tags: php, aes, cryptojs

I have a working JS which successfully encodes and decodes data, however, i just tried to replicate the same thing in PHP and when i do that, the JS decode is able to return me a right value, however, that PHP encode output is rejected by the server.

I have no access to the backend.

Here is the working JS:

```
let u = CryptoJS;

function decrypt(e) {
  let t = (e = u.enc.Base64.parse(e)).toString(u.enc.Utf8);
  t = JSON.parse(t);
  let a = u.enc.Base64.parse(t.iv);
  var n = u.AES.decrypt(
    t.value,
    u.enc.Utf8.parse([KEY]),
    {
      iv: a,
      mode: u.mode.CBC,
      padding: u.pad.Pkcs7
    }
  );
  return (n = u.enc.Utf8.stringify(n));
}

function encrypt(e) {
  let t = u.lib.WordArray.random(16),
    a = u.enc.Utf8.parse([KEY]),
    n = { iv: t, mode: u.mode.CBC, padding: u.pad.Pkcs7 },
    l = u.AES.encrypt(e, a, n);
  (l = l.toString()), (t = u.enc.Base64.stringify(t));
  let r = {
    iv: t,
    value: l,
    mac: u.HmacSHA256(t + l, a).toString()
  };
  return (
    (r = JSON.stringify(r)),
    (r = u.enc.Utf8.parse(r)),
    u.enc.Base64.stringify(r)
  );
}
```

And the PHP which does produce a return, which JS decodes tight with the same key but this one is rejected by the server, where the JS encode one, which decodes the same value with JS decode, is accepted:

```
function enc($plainData,$secrete_key){

    $key = base64_decode($secrete_key);
    $iv = base64_encode(random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC')));

    $value = openssl_encrypt($plainData, 'AES-256-CBC', $secrete_key, 0, base64_decode($iv));

    $mac = hash('sha256', $iv.$value.$secrete_key);
    $json = json_encode(["iv"=>$iv,"value"=>$value,"mac"=>$mac], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    return base64_encode($json);
}

$data = [
    "start_date" => "2023-07-23 00:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2023-07-23 23:59:59",
    "graph_uuid" => "1234567890",
    "ignore_zero" => true,
];

$enc = enc(json_encode($data),env(KEY))
```

Any idea what i'm missing here?

My first suspect was the single vs double quotes but i have no idea what's on the server side.

Comment: For `t = u.lib.WordArray.random(16)` assuming "Word" to mean "8 bits" then your IV, and therefore block, size is 128. Try changing the cipher to `AES-128-CBC`. Aside from that we'd need to see an example output from both JS and PHP, using the same IV, and including example encryption keys. If we can't reproduce the issue locally, then all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Here is the playground example with fake key and other params: php: https://tehplayground.com/eDp21TAfCS3djZHS js: https://codepen.io/mariotanenbaum/pen/qBQMxgX

Comment: Ok I'll amend my previous comment to say that CryptoJS picks the block sized based on the _key_, which is 256 bits. However your IV is still 128bits. I believe that OpenSSL zero-pads the IV to the correct size, but I haven't been able to find what CryptoJS's behaviour is in this case, and I suspect that it differs.

Comment: The ciphertexts differ (even with identical IV) because in the PHP code 1. not the HMAC is determined (but erroneously the hash) and 2. the slashes are escaped (unlike in the CryptoJS code). If this is fixed, the ciphertexts are identical (with identical IV).

Comment: Thnx man. Just put an answer, i'm gonna accept it.